# Problems containing multiple "or" operators in C

Tags: c

I was solving some problems related to "or" operators in C.

The body of the program was like what mentioned below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
    int i = 4, j = -1, k = 0, w, x, y, z;
    w = i || j || k ;
    x = i && j && k ;
    z = i && j || k ;

    printf("\n w=%d ,  x = %d", w, x);
    printf("\n y=%d , z = %d", y, z);
}
```

Can someone please tell me the mechanism of these statements?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I think w = 1 , x = 0 , z=1

Comment: why are you printing Y?

Comment: Remember that the logical operators in C uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and the zero is "false" and everything non-zero (including negative numbers) is "true".

Comment: Imagine that there is a `!=0` next to each variable name, i.e. `w = i!=0 || j!=0 || k!=0;` That is what C does implicitly for you.

Comment: every non-zero is supposed "true" and zero is "false"

Comment: But how do I calculate the value of ( i || j || k; ) ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Hey! So if there are "||" operators between non zero values, it will give 1 and if there's even one "0" in an "&&" operator sysyem, it will give 0. Is it like that?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are binary operators, they take two arguments. When confronted with a more complicated expression you can break it down into sets of binary operations.

For example, `z = i && j || k;` could be written as `z = ( (i && j) || k )`. Or in pictorial form:

```
    z
    =
    ||
   /  \
  &&   k
 / \
i   j
```

To know that the tree has this layout we look up *operator precedence* (or language grammar rules), the rule is that to choose between `&&` and `||`, the `||` is the 'outer' operation (i.e. lower precedence).

These operators also do short-circuiting, although that is not relevant in this particular example.

So, looking at the above table, `i && j` gives `1` because both `i` and `j` are non-zero.   The `1 || k` gives `1` because at least one of the operands is non-zero. Finaly `1` is assigned to `z`.

You can find the right values for `w` and `x` in a similar way, using the precedence rule that the left-most `&&` is the inner one, when the situation is `a && b && c`, and similarly for `||`.

Answer (score -2):

the || and && operators are logical operators, which means they evaluate the numbers as either 'true' or 'false'

In that sense, i and j are 'true' and k is 'false'. So, calculating the outcome:

w = 'true' or 'true' or 'false' = true = 1

x = 'true' and 'true' and 'false' = false = 0

z = 'true' and 'true' or 'false' = true = 1

y isn't defined and will contain 0 or garbage

--edit--

note that && and || are left to right operators, therefore the first operator is always evaluated first.

Comment: You should cover associativity and order of operations (especially in case Z)